# I am facing difficulty to show Google Map after click on Button in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an app in android.

In this app i want to show google Map after click on button.

I have declared button and i declared listener.

But my problem is i want to call another activity class in the action listener and show google map.

But it is not working, I changed emulator from google to Android it work but google API is not called  and shows me error.

for this i used this code But my Map is not show and my Application is Terminated .

//----------------Main Activity ---------------//

```
import java.security.PublicKey;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText TextFeild;
Button button1;
Context context=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addOnListenerAction();


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new                PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void addOnListenerAction()
{
    TextFeild=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapViwer.class);

        }
    });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

//_-------------------MapViwer Class------------//

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

 public class MapViwer extends MapActivity
  {
MapView map;
public void onCreate(Bundle setInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(setInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying, you have a `class` named (MapViwer) that defines a `layout` and the `class` (MapViwer) contains information for the map to work. To deploy a class from your `MainActivity.class`, use the following method.

in `MainActivity`, under the `public class` add this

```
private Button button1;
```

then add this function -

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapViwer.class);
       startActivityForResult(i, 100);          
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this..It worked for me..

```
Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapViewer.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       }
});
```

and in the Mapviewer class just call the mapviewer.xml

Now, the mapviewer.xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try it out..

Answer (score 0):

Replace **context** with **Mainactivity.this** in the code
**Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapViwer.class);**
You just only defined intent but didn't call the **Mapviewr activity**

Correct code:

```
   public void addOnListenerAction()
 {
  TextFeild=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Mainactivity.this,MapViwer.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

}